# How to hide filepath input file?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need help with javascript and some html i guess.

I have a input file  button where I can choose an image and upload it, but I want to remove the "filepath" name, or at least hide it. Is that possible to do, if so how do I do that?

I am able to hide the "no file chosen" by using

but I am not able to do the same for hiding the filepath.

I've tried to use that, and to use `onclick` and so one but nothing seems to work.

Comment: produce the code that you have used.

Comment: I think you are looking for custom file upload button . e.i https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/custom-file-input-styling-webkitblink/

Answer (score 0):

Use display none for the input type file, and include a button with id='x' in your page.

Add a eventlistener for click on button x and when it does trigger a onchange event for input type file. It works.

Answer (score 0):

Just hiding the whole thing and putting a separate button object which, when clicked, will end up clicking the input's browse button.

You can do this with the help of CSS & javascript

[click here](http://www.shauninman.com/archive/2007/09/10/styling_file_inputs_with_css_and_the_dom)